# Variable supporting class like attribute assignments

Tags: python

I was wondering if there was some kind of python variable (which isn't a custom made class) which would support the following code :

```
a = some_creation_procedure
a.variable_a = 1
a.variable_b = 2
a.variable_c = 3
print ("{}, {}, {}".format(a.variable_a, a.variable_b, a.variable_c))
```

output -

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

I could probably create a custom class and support this with "get_attribute" function, but I was wondering if there was a built-in support for this.

**Motivation:**

I want to debug a certain function within a class (Which requires a lot of operations / variables for initliazing), so I want to create a sub-class instance which has variables corresponding to that specific function (and send it as self for that specific function).

for example :

```
class some_class():
    def __init__(var1, var2, var3, var4 , ....):
        do_a()
        do_b()
        and so on...

    def minimal_func(self):
        print (self.var1)

    my_variable.var1 = "a"
    some_class.minimal_func(my_variable)
```

Comment: If your class has so many unused attributes, it might be a sign that your class hierarchy isn't right. Maybe consider splitting it into multiple smaller classes?

Comment: @Aran-Fey He just says for this function unused.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Actually the minimal function uses only one variable for breaking up a bigger function. My class is pretty well though of hierarchy wise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is a class without anything inside it:

```
class Namespace: pass

a = Namespace()
a.variable_a = 1
a.variable_b = 2
a.variable_c = 3
print ("{}, {}, {}".format(a.variable_a, a.variable_b, a.variable_c))
```

prints:

```
1, 2, 3
```

as @James said in the comments:

> Instances of class objects can have attributes assigned to them on the fly. There are ways to restrict attribute assignment as well, but by default, you can just assign anything

As @Aran-Frey pointed out, you can also use the [types.SimpleNamespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace) class instead of of the above empty class:

```
import types
a = types.SimpleNamespace()
```

This also allows you to add attributes in the constructor:

```
import types

a = types.SimpleNamespace(
    variable_a=1,
    variable_b=2,
    variable_c=3)
```

Also it has a nice `__repr__` function:

```
print(a)
```

prints:

```
namespace(variable_a=1, variable_b=2, variable_c=3)
```

Comment: Seems like this exactly what I need, could you expand a bit on what you did there?

Comment: Instances of class objects can have attributes assigned to them on the fly.  There are ways to restrict attribute assignment as well, but by default, you can just assign

Comment: @James Thanks, megalng - ill accept the answer as soon as the site allows me :)

Comment: There's also [`types.SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace) in case you don't want to roll your own. It offers some advantages like keyword arguments in the constructor: `a = SimpleNamespace(a=1, b=2)` and a nice `repr`.

Comment: @Rohi This is really no different to how you attach an attribute to an instance in (for example) the class's `__init__` method, except that inside a method you normally refer to the instance via `self`, but it's really the same thing. `self` isn't some kind of magic syntax, it's just a name that's used by convention.

Comment: @PM2Ring I realize that and its pretty trivial, I just wanted to skip the class creation part.

Comment: @Rohi If you don't want to create a class, I edited another alternative into the answer

Comment: Just for fun: `a = type('Namespace', (), {})(); a.a, a.b, a.c = 1, 2, 3; print(a, a.a, a.b, a.c)`. You probably shouldn't do that in real code though. :)